# Import packages depending from OS version

Tags: swift

When I'm writing a code, I can use `@available` and `#available` directives, e.g.:

```
@available(watchOS 10.0, *)
    class ClassWhichUsesNewfunctions: NSObject {
}
```

but they doesn't work in `import` section. Obviously, I want my app could be used on previous OS versions too, so I can't simply change target's destination.

I tried

```
if #available(watchOS 10.0, *){
    import WorkoutKit
}
```

and

```
@available(watchOS 10.0, *)
import WorkoutKit
```

but both of them gives compilation errors `Statements are not allowed at the top level`  and `'@available' attribute cannot be applied to this declaration`

So how could I import newest packages? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Surely ```import``` is a compiler directive, it doesn't determine what goes into your app. Where you actually use the symbols from a package is where you need to put the version checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way, you can use the `canImport` macro in this circumstance. i.e

```swift
#if canImport(WorkoutKit)
import WorkoutKit
#else
import Foundation
#endif

func doStuff() {
    #if canImport(WorkoutKit)
    print(SingleGoalWorkout(activity: .bowling))
    #else
    print("No workout here")
    #endif
}
```